# py2neo transactions unbound pattern

Tags: py2neo, neo4j

I am trying to create a NEO4j cypher transaction using the py2neo library following the example on:

http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/cypher/#id2

When executing and committing the transaction I get the error:

py2neo.cypher.InvalidSemantics: Unbound pattern!

I'm using the py2neo 1.6.3 library and the newest 2.01 of NEO4j. Does anyone have insight please?

Comment: py2neo 1.6.4 has been released today! Check to see if it has any fixes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a documentation bug on my part where I had uploaded broken Cypher. The example has now been corrected.